# Have aliases in adb shell non-interactive mode

Tags: android, unix, sh, adb, mksh

Hi I need to run things in the form of `adb shell <command>`

When I test everything out inside adb shell, it works because I was able to set some aliases in `.bashrc`.
However, when I do `adb shell <command>`, nothing works because `.bashrc` is not used when you run `adb shell <command>`, because it's in the non-interactive mode.

How can I work around this? Can I `adb push` some files to the filesystem so that the alias will be there when `adb shell` is run?

Comment: Why not just do the alias substitution in whatever is generating the commands?

Answer (score 16):

If your android device is rooted you can add your aliases for `adb shell` into the `/system/etc/mkshrc` file.

Comment: If you get a "Read-only file system" error, boot into TWRP or whatever custom recovery, mount system, then edit the file.

Comment: A got that read-only error, but booting into TWRP didn't work for me, because /system didn't have the `etc/mkshrc` file as when booted normally. I used `mount -o remount,rw /system` without booting into TWRP to mount `/system` read-write.

Comment: @JohannesBittner ... to complement your excellent comment: To remount read-only again (for security reasons) use this command in a terminal as root (su): `mount -o remount,ro /system`

Comment: @R Yoda.        Nowadays since android 9, use `/` instead of `/system`.
`mount -o,rw $(mount | grep /dev/root | awk '{print $3}'` does the job for any android version.

Comment: oops missed closing bracket etc.

`mount -o rw,remount $(mount | grep /dev/root | awk '{print $3}')`

Comment: Adding alias to `/system/etc/mkshrc` only works after getting the `adb shell` prompt.  It does *not* work if the alias is invoked using `adb shell "<the-added-alias>"`.  (I have a rooted Android-10 based device).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to issue several shell commands in a single ADB command. You can put them in a string, and separate them with semicolons, thus:

`adb shell "alias foo bar ; export MY_VARIABLE=/path/to/somewhere ; my_executable "`

The `"` are crucial here, make sure they are paired up correctly. You could run your `.bashrc` this way, thus:

`adb shell "source /path/to/.bashrc ; my_executable"`

Answer (score -3):

You can write a bash script that sets the aliases and then executes your shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
. $HOME/.bashrc
adb shell $@
```

Comment: This will not work as written. The shell on Android is not bash, and is not in /usr/bin.